# is there a way to select the MAX value with JObject SelectTokens?

Tags: c#, json.net

let's say from the following JSON I want to select the product with the max price:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'Stores': [
    'Lambton Quay',
    'Willis Street'
  ],
  'Manufacturers': [
    {
      'Name': 'Acme Co',
      'Products': [
        {
          'Name': 'Anvil',
          'Price': 50
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      'Name': 'Contoso',
      'Products': [
        {
          'Name': 'Elbow Grease',
          'Price': 99.95
        },
        {
          'Name': 'Headlight Fluid',
          'Price': 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}");
```

like this for example:

```
IEnumerable<JToken> pricyProducts = o.SelectTokens("$..Products[?(MAX(@.Price))].Name");
```

Does anybody have an idea how to get the max/min value ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, [JsonPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) does not define a `MAX` function, and none has been implemented in Json.Net.  You could use LINQ-to-JSON queries instead to get the result you want:

```cs
IEnumerable<JObject> products = o.SelectTokens("$..Products")
                                 .SelectMany(a => a.Children<JObject>());

decimal maxPrice = products.Max(p => (decimal)p["Price"]);

IEnumerable<JToken> pricyProducts = products.Where(p => (decimal)p["Price"] == maxPrice)
                                            .Select(p => p["Name"]);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/i4wkrv

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted to avoid, too much code, thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, you could wrap the above code in an extension method to make it easier to use.  The only other alternative I can see is to modify the Json.Net source code to implement the feature yourself.